# How do I get just one category to show up on my volunteer template?

Tags: java, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get just one category "Children" to display on this page but it is pulling all of my categories.

Here is some **code**:

```
//category options
$categories = $_GET['categories'];
$day = $_GET['day'];
$childcare = $_GET['childcare'];
$category;
$categoryTitles;
$categoryArray = array();
if($categories!=''){
array_push($categoryArray, $categories);
}
if($day!=''){
array_push($categoryArray, $day);
}
if($childcare!=''){
array_push($categoryArray, $childcare);
}
array_push($categoryArray,"volunteer");//the last one should be 
volunteer parent category

if(count($categoryArray) > 0){
$category = implode("&&",$categoryArray);
}
```

Am I missing something?

I have tried every way I can think of to get JUST children to show up.

Comment: Where are you you checking for `Children`?

Comment: How is this related to [tag:java]?

Comment: Please include some sample data of what you would expect to be in `$_GET['childcare']` and `$_GET['categories']`